# User Configurable C# Windows Service Application

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows Service that processes some files in a directory.
I need to add some configuration information - the directory path and the frequency of the processing.

The user need to be able to modify the configuration.

I tried modifying app.config outside of the application in notepad, but the changes do not come through; a settings file does the same thing.

Start parameters do work, but that puts a burden on the administrator every time the service needs to start.

What is the best way to add user configurable info to the application?

Comment: Using an application configuration file should work (make sure you place it next to the executable of your service and name it alike, e.g. myservice.exe.config) Also, you need to restart your service for changes to be picked up.

Comment: "Changes do not come through" - Did you refresh them with `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection` in the service?

Comment: Some more detail needed here. Did you install the service or are you simply debugging it? The app.config is normally only the name used in visual studio. It will take the [name of your service].exe.config as soon as you build it or install it.

Comment: @mikez ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection was the solution, thank you. Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `ConfigurationManager` class caches the values from the configuration file. If you need to get updated values, use `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection` to update the desired section. (MSDN [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx))